# jquery and javascript conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery in the master page and javascript in the content page. When Jquery is used alone it works fine. But when I use the javascript(content page) along with jquery(master page) then jquery in master page stops working.

**master page script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// set up the accordion
$("#accordion>h3").click(function() {
    $(this).next("div").slideToggle(500).siblings("div").slideUp(500);
});

// show active menu section
setTimeout('$("#accordion>div.activesec").slideToggle(800)', 100);
```

});

**content page script**

```
$('slideshow').style.display = 'none';
$('wrapper').style.display = 'block';
var slideshow = new TINY.slideshow("slideshow");
window.onload = function () {
    slideshow.auto = true;
    slideshow.speed = 5;
    slideshow.link = "linkhover";
    slideshow.info = "information";
    slideshow.thumbs = "slider";
    slideshow.left = "slideleft";
    slideshow.right = "slideright";
    slideshow.scrollSpeed = 4;
    slideshow.spacing = 5;
    slideshow.active = "#fff";
    slideshow.init("slideshow", "image", "imgprev", "imgnext", "imglink");
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the JavaScript console for errors?

Comment: $("#accordion>h3") is null is the error on console

Comment: Well, that would have been useful to add to the question :) Do you have the `#accordion` element with a `h3` tag inside in the HTML?

Comment: yes juhana. something like <div id="accordion"><h3>test-1</h3><ul><li>the list items goes here</li></ul></div>

Comment: Also, the content script looks very much like Prototype. Does the page load prototype.js?

Comment: http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/javascript-slideshow/ I am using this one on the content page. this is a javascript based slideshow

Comment: @Juhana let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2107/discussion-between-sam-and-juhana)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like the other script uses `$`, just like jQuery. You need to use `$.noConflict()` to prevent namespace clashes:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {

// set up the accordion
$j("#accordion>h3").click(function() {
    $j(this).next("div").slideToggle(500).siblings("div").slideUp(500);
});

// show active menu section
setTimeout('$j("#accordion>div.activesec").slideToggle(800)', 100);
```

If you don't want to use `$j` instead of `$` in all jQuery functions, you can wrap everything (except the content page scripts!) in a function that assigns `$` to jQuery:

```
(function( $ ){
  // everything inside works normally with $
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: great juhana. it works. thanks a lot. i tried using jquery.conflict() directly but no luck, this will solves the issue. have a great time.. cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the collision is caused by your use of the `$` shorthand in the content page. `$` is used to represent jQuery. So, jQuery is trying to interpret `$('slideshow').style.display` , which is not valid jQuery.

Replace your shorthand with document.getElementById, or use jQuery selectors.

**Standard JS**

```
document.getElementById.style.display = 'none';
```

**Or jQuery**

```
$('slideshow').css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: @sam, You know it's case sensitive right? `document.getElementById('yourIdHere')`. Also, what do you mean still the same? What error do you get?

Comment: sorry james I am using the right case as you mentioned. $("#accordion>h3") is null is the error on firefox console. I understand the javascript $ conflicts the one in jquery thats why I am getting the null error.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your selections are missing "#" or "." depending on weather your trying to access an id or class

```
$('#slideshow').style.display = 'none';
$('#wrapper').style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: This is not correct. A jQuery object doesn't have a `.style` property.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string to the `setTimeout` parameter. Really bad.

```
$('slideshow').style.display = 'none';
```

You are trying to find `<slideshow>` tags with jQuery, maybe you are missing a class or ID selector?

Also, the `style` method is not a jQuery method asfar as I know, so maybe you will want to call it on a JavaScript object instead of a jQuery one? Or perhaps use the `.css` method on it?

Comment: this is javascript on the content page

Answer (score -1):

Did u put ur plane javascript inside the :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
});
```

If yes then try to put them outside it.

Answer (score -1):

Best practice would be to put all your Javascript/Jquery code in a .js file.  Then import this .js in the page that need it.

This way your HTML will be clean and not cluttered with javascript all over the place.

I know i don't really answer your problem, but working this way you will probably help avoid it.

good luck

Comment: yes i did placed them separately.but still the conflict occurs